# NuGet unable to add older versions of a dll

Tags: xamarin, nuget, mvvmcross, nuget-package

I need to install version 3.0.14 of MvvmCross.Plugin.Location since I am way behind the times.
Issued command nuget install mvvmcross.hottuna.plugin.location 3.0.14 and received

install-package : No compatible project(s) found in the active solution.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Location 3.0.14
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetNoCompatibleProjects,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Navigated my packages folder and the specific folder in question is there:

MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Location.3.0.14

and within this folder are the

Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Location.dll and 
Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Location.WindowsPhone.dll

I can manually add these but would prefer to do so via NuGet.  What is the deal here?

Comment: What kind of project do you have, and which profile do you use? For example if you use iOS unified, it wouldn't have a compatible package and give an error like this.

Comment: This is a Windows Phone 8.0 project.  I have am using other MvvmCross 3.0.14 plugins and have since posted this question manually added reference to the dlls referenced above without issues so far.